# Javascript array for AJAX POST send

Tags: html, ajax, arrays, post, send

Here is the deal... I need to make an AJAX save script. I have a whole system built on php and every action needs a refresh... I'm trying to minimize the refresh count by using AJAX ... I can't seem to find a way how to send a WYSIWYG editor output without loss to the PHP script...

```
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
function save(){
    xmlhttp.open('POST','action.php',true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", document.getElementById('output').value.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(document.getElementById('output').value);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            $('#ajaxresult').css('opacity', 0.1);
            $('#ajaxresult').stopAll().pause(1000).fadeTo(400,1);
            $('#ajaxresult').stopAll().pause(3000).fadeTo(400,0, function(){$(this).hide();});
            document.getElementById('ajaxresult').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

While this script works fine I can't seem to find the way what kind of array to give the send option... what is the syntax or is there something I don't know?

BTW I'm a beginner in JS...

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into using jQuery and it's Ajax library:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Instead of doing all that you'd simply do:

```
$.post({url: 'action.php',data: output,success: function() { /* do something here */ }});
```

Comment: The problem is the data field...
How do I prepare the POST array so that id doesn't loose data...

For example if I want to write the following variables a=1 and b=33 and c='šaize kaut kāda un vēl sazin žuķīļņšģīŗ'...

Now a and b will be perfect, but c will be cut off at some point most likely loosing just the š ā ē ž ķ and so on... I need it to contain all possible characters and not ignore them as it is doing right now...

Comment: I would recommend as well to use jQuery or some other Ajax library.

Answer (score 1):

create **custom parameter** in the javascript code like below:

```
   var jspNameParam = "content="+escape(document.getElementById('output').value);
    function myFunction() {
        if (xmlhttp) {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                /*  want to accsess some data written from action.php */
                }   
            };          
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "action.php", true);   
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(jspNameParam);
        }
    }
```

Now in action.php you will get whole content with the parameter name **content**.